# Using AFNetwork on a local server?

Tags: json, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

So I have configured a raspberry pi to use as a hotspot, but the Pi does not have internet access. It should only serve as a hotspot for me to connect through wifi in order to get access to the server I have stored on the raspberry.

I then want to get data from the server, as json, using AFNetwork. The problem is that I get the error code that I don't have an internet connection. I am connected to the raspberry and can view the data on it, but I can't seem to get the data to my app using AFNetwork.

I'm using this example project: http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial and I've changed the base url to an url displaying json through 192.168.etc. If I simply paste the url in the browser I see my json data. Is it possible to use AFNetwork like this or does it require an internet connection?

Thanks!

Edit: I tried going online and doing a request to an url containing json data and it worked fine. So not having internet connection seems to be the issue for AFNetwork.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Seems like the problem was with the Simulator in Xcode. It didn't really like to switch between different networks, so closing it and opening it made the connection possible. In case anyone else is trying to do the same thing.